# Redux Saga - Complex control flow

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I am coming from Redux Thunk so I am brand new to Redux Saga. I have managed to implement some simple takeEvery calls but I am struggling with a more complex solution and wonder if you might be able to point me in the right direction.

I am creating an warehouse application that uses Redux Persist to store picked orders offline and then periodically sync them back to the server when I have a connection. In order to sync them I have two api call I need to make independently and in order:

1. Update picked quantity
2. Confirm the pick

I have attached a sample of my Redux state below. If you look at the ordersToSync I must first post back (individually) the PickedQuantity and the PickingListDetailId with the first method and confirm the pick with the PickListId using the second method.

So far I have managed to create an es6 generator to simulate the behaviour I want with some flags to check connectivity, whether the data is syncing or if there is an error. If you copy and paste the code I have attached into https://stephengrider.github.io/JSPlaygrounds/ and check the console you with see the desired outcome.

I am struggling with the concept of applying this to Redux Saga so this process can work in the background as non-blocking calls. Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Many thanks in advance.

```
    // Example Sync Queue (Persisted Redux state)
    const ordersToSync = [
        {
        "pickingListId": 2362,
        "itemsPicked": [
          {
            "PickingListDetailId": 3115,
            "ProductId": 3387,
            "ProductSKU": "123XP",
            "ProductTitle": "Frameset",
            "PickQuantity": 2,
            "PickedQuantity": 2
          },
          {
            "PickingListDetailId": 3114,
            "ProductId": 3386,
            "ProductSKU": "123XP",
            "ProductTitle": "Frameset",
            "PickQuantity": 3,
            "PickedQuantity": 1
          },
          {
            "PickingListDetailId": 3116,
            "ProductId": 3385,
            "ProductSKU": "123XP",
            "ProductTitle": "Frameset",
            "PickQuantity": 4,
            "PickedQuantity": 4
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "pickingListId": 2374,
        "itemsPicked": [
          {
            "PickingListDetailId": 3105,
            "ProductId": 3088,
            "ProductSKU": "123XP",
            "ProductTitle": "Frameset",
            "PickQuantity": 1,
            "PickedQuantity": 1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "pickingListId": 2322,
        "itemsPicked": [
          {
            "PickingListDetailId": 3101,
            "ProductId": 3187,
            "ProductSKU": "123XP",
            "ProductTitle": "Frameset",
            "PickQuantity": 2,
            "PickedQuantity": 2
          },
          {
            "PickingListDetailId": 3118,
            "ProductId": 3286,
            "ProductSKU": "123XP",
            "ProductTitle": "Frameset",
            "PickQuantity": 3,
            "PickedQuantity": 1
          },
          {
            "PickingListDetailId": 3125,
            "ProductId": 3325,
            "ProductSKU": "123XP",
            "ProductTitle": "Frameset",
            "PickQuantity": 4,
            "PickedQuantity": 4
          }
        ]
      },
    ];

    // Represents Redux Reducer
    const error = false; // Flip if error comes back from axios request
    const syncing = false; // Flip whilst axios request does its thing
    const connectionType = 'WIFI'; // Toggled by

    // ES6 generator for dispatching sync actions
    function* OrderIterator() {
      // If we have a suitable connection (NetInfo connection type)
      if (connectionType === 'WIFI') {
        // If we are not already syncing some data
        // And we have no errors
        if (!syncing && !error) {
          for (const order of ordersToSync) {
            for (const item of order.itemsPicked) {
              // Dispatch updatePickQuantityAction
              // 1. Flip the syncing state to true UPDATE_PICK_QUANTITY_START
              // 2. If there is an error stop everything and flip the error state to true UPDATE_PICK_QUANTITY_FAIL
              // 3. If everything goes well with the request, flip the syncing state to false and carry on UPDATE_PICK_QUANTITY_SUCCESS
              yield console.log(`this.props.updatePickQuantityAction(${item.PickedQuantity}, ${item.PickingListDetailId});`);
            }
            if(!syncing && !error) {
              // Dispatch confirmPickAction
              // 1. Flip the syncing state to true CONFIRM_PICK_START
              // 2. If there is an error stop everything and flip the error state to true CONFIRM_PICK_FAIL
              // 3. If everything goes well with the request, flip the syncing state to false and carry on CONFIRM_PICK_SUCCESS
                yield console.log(`this.props.confirmPickAction(${order.pickingListId});`);
            }
            // Dispatch removeConfirmedPickAction
            // This will remove the pick from sync queue (Redux state not API) after it has been confirmed
            console.log(`this.props.removeConfirmedPickAction();`);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    const SyncOrders = OrderIterator();

    for (const item of SyncOrders) {
        item;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
export const ordersToSync = state => state.ordersToSync;
export const getLastSavedItemId = state => state.lastSavedItemId;
export const getItemFailedOnConfirm = state => state.itemFailedOnCofirm;

export function *syncDataIdea() {
  const ordersToSync = yield select(ordersToSync);
  for (const order of ordersToSync) {
    for (const item of order.itemsPicked) {
      yield call(updatePickQuantityAction, item.PickedQuantity);
    }
    yield call(confirmPickAction, order.pickingListId);
    yield call(removeConfirmedPickAction, order.pickingListId);
  }
}

export function *syncData() {
  const ordersToSync = yield select(ordersToSync);
  for (const order of ordersToSync) {
    const itemFailedOnConfirm = yield select(getItemFailedOnConfirm);
    if (itemFailedOnConfirm === null) {
      const lastSavedItemId = yield select(getLastSavedItemId);
      for (const item of order.itemsPicked) {
        const itemId = item.PickedQuantity.PickingListDetailId;
        try {
          if (lastSavedItemId !== null
            && lastSavedItemId !== itemId) {
            continue;
          }
          yield call(updatePickQuantityAction, item.PickedQuantity);
          yield put({type: 'SET_LAST_SAVED_ITEM', getLastSavedItemId: null});
        }
        catch (error) {
          yield put({
            type: 'SET_LAST_SAVED_ITEM', getLastSavedItemId: itemId
          });
        }
        finally {
          if (yield cancelled()) {
            yield put({
              type: 'SET_LAST_SAVED_ITEM', getLastSavedItemId: itemId
            });
          }
        }
      }
    }
    try {
      yield call(confirmPickAction, order.pickingListId);
      yield put({type: 'ITEM_FAILED_ON_CONFIRM', pickingListId: null});
    }
    catch (error) {
      yield put({type: 'ITEM_FAILED_ON_CONFIRM', pickingListId: order.pickingListId});
    }
    finally {
      if (yield cancelled()) {
        yield put({type: 'ITEM_FAILED_ON_CONFIRM', pickingListId: order.pickingListId});
      }
    }
    yield call(removeConfirmedPickAction, order.pickingListId);
  }
}

function* main() {
  while (yield take('WIFI_ON')) {
    const syncDataTask = yield fork(syncData);
    yield take('WIFI_OFF');
    yield cancel(syncDataTask);
  }
}
```

Please note, I'm also a quite new to `redux-saga`. I would suggest you to take a look on https://redux-saga.github.io/redux-saga/docs/advanced/TaskCancellation.html